# Two alignment points in equation

Tags: align

I want to align these set of equations at two places, but gaps appear whatever I try.

Basically, I want to align the first two rows at the beginning. At the same time, I want to align the third row with the second row at the + sign.

Could someone help?

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&P(t_{n+1}-t_n>q) =\exp\left( -\int_{t_n}^{t_n+q}\lambda(t) dt \right)\notag\\
&\simeq e^{-\lambda_0q}\biggl(1 &&+ \int_{t_n}^{t_n+q}\lambda_1(t)dt \\
& &&+ \int_{t_n}^{t_n+q}\int_{t_n}^{t_n+q}\lambda_1(t)\lambda_1(t')dtdt'  \biggr)\,.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use multiple alignment points, I just used a nested `aligned` environment.

I also added a `\!` before the `\simeq` to remove the associated `\mathrel` spacing to the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&P(t_{n+1}-t_n>q) =\exp\left( -\int_{t_n}^{t_n+q}\lambda(t) dt \right)\notag\\
&\!\simeq e^{-\lambda_0q}\biggl(1 
\begin{aligned}[t]
&+ \int_{t_n}^{t_n+q}\lambda_1(t)dt \\
&+ \int_{t_n}^{t_n+q}\int_{t_n}^{t_n+q}\lambda_1(t)\lambda_1(t')dtdt'  \biggr)\,.
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The more traditional appearance would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
P(t_{n+1}-t_n>q) &=\exp\left( -\int_{t_n}^{t_n+q}\lambda(t) dt \right)\notag\\
&\simeq e^{-\lambda_0q}\biggl(1 
\begin{aligned}[t]
&+ \int_{t_n}^{t_n+q}\lambda_1(t)dt \\
&+ \int_{t_n}^{t_n+q}\int_{t_n}^{t_n+q}\lambda_1(t)\lambda_1(t')dtdt'  \biggr)\,.
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]